# Why does std::copy (from istream to ostream) raises an ios::failure exception?

Tags: c++, stl, stream

The following code should copy data from an wifstream to wcout.
After the content is copied, the program throws a ios::failure exception.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


int main(void)
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));

    std::wifstream is;
    is.exceptions( std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit );
    is.open("test.ts", std::ios::binary);

    is >> std::noskipws;

    std::istream_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t> in(is);
    std::istream_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t> end;

    std::copy(in, end,
              std::ostream_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t>(std::wcout));

    return 0;
}
```

The stream should only throw an exception (see exception mask) if anything goes bad, but not on EOF.

Comment: Setting stream exceptions seems like a good idea, but it often doesn't work as you expect.  Instead, just check the stream state before using input, e.g. `if (stream >> var) {/*only now use var*/}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid skipping white space use the std::istreambuf_iterator

```
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t>(is),
          std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t>(std::wcout));
```

The exception:

The local may be using codecvt facet that is failing.
Try commenting out the locale line see what happens.

Have you tried to print what the exceptions is?

```
try
{
    // do work
}
catch(std::exception const& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Looks nice, but the noskipws does not cause the exception. Even if I uncomment it, there's an exception.

Comment: There's a typo, the second argument to istreambuf_iterator is a trait class.

Comment: The exception message is: basic_ios::clear and even if I remove the global locale the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `std::istream_iterator`, the attempt to read a character past the end of the stream sets both `eofbit` and `failbit` (and only after some error bits are set, does the iterator become equal to the end iterator)

Stripping to bare essentials and reverting to char to make it even simpler, program is equivalent to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream is("test.txt", std::ios::binary);
    is.exceptions(std::ios::failbit); // failbit only because that's what you get
    is >> std::noskipws;
    if(is)
        for(char c; is >> c;) // will throw!
            std::cout << c;
}
```

Comment: Not quite equivalent, but this would be: `for (char c; is >> c;) cout << c;`

Comment: @Roger Pate As far as I understand, `std::copy` will not execute `operator>>` even once if the stream is already in failed state (and input iterator is already equal to the end iterator) therefore while(is).

Answer (score 0):

According to §27.6.1.2.3/10:

> After a sentry object is constructed a character is extracted from *in*, if one is available, and stored in *c*. Otherwise, the function calls *in.setstate(failbit)*.

So, when it reaches the end of the file and can no longer extract a character, it will set the fail bit, which you've set to produce an exception. Using `std::copy` doesn't change the behavior -- an `istream_iterator` reads via `operator>>`.

You can copy the file a bit more easily:

```
std::wifstream is("test.ts", std::ios::binary);
std::wcout << is.rdbuf();
```

Comment: It does not make any sense to me. If the underlaying streambuf returns traits_type::eof(), the stream should only set the eof bit, not fail bit.

Comment: If it said that `operator>>` would return without attempting a conversion if the eof bit was set, then that would happen -- but it doesn't. Even if the eof bit is set, it still attempts a conversion, which fails, so the fail bit gets set.

Comment: @cytrinox: eofbit is set and then op>> causes failbit to be set.